# MSTest no xml output on .NET Core RC2

Tags: mstest, .net-core, dotnet-cli

I'm targeting `dotnet-test-mstest": "1.0.1-preview` on dotnet core rc2 in my test project.

**Edit:**
Okay. I'm targeting the the desktop .NET. But this should not make any difference.

project.json

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",

    "testRunner": "mstest",

    "dependencies": {
        "Betgame": "1.0.0-*",
        "dotnet-test-mstest": "1.0.1-preview",
        "MSTest.TestAdapter": "1.0.0-preview",
        "MSTest.TestFramework": "1.0.0-preview",
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.5.0-rc2-24027"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "net461": { }
    }
}
```

output when running `dotnet test` looks quite good!

[image]

How can i get the output as a xml file to process this in my build process? Any ideas? Or is it just not yet supported?

So far i tried `dotnet test -xml test-results.xml` but no output was generated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you for trying out the MSTest release.
Please use the following to generate a trx report (xml file):

```
vstest.console.exe project.json /UseVsixExtensions:true /logger:trx
```

The report gets generated in a TestResults folder.

Comment: Right now this works on my local machine. Thanks man! Trying to solve this on my TFS Online build

Comment: Also solved it on TFS Online Build! Struggled a little with the absolute and relative paths. But in the end it worked! :)

Comment: This is not a solution for Linux and Mac OS X

Comment: Thank you so much! This saved my day - now test results keep on coming in my VSTS build :-)

Comment: If you are targeting .NET Core and running the tests inside VSTS, have a look at this page: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/09/01/announcing-mstest-v2-framework-support-for-net-core-1-0-rtm

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the decompiled code of dotnet-test-mstest, I don't see any `-xml` option or anything similar. So I think it's not currently supported.

Comment: hm. that is pretty sad. any idea how to get test result output? Wait for new dotnet-test-mstest versions?