# VSTS build of .NET Core 1.0 VSTest Warning: No test is available

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, .net-core

I recently switched all of my unit tests over from xunit to mstest, and on my local dev machine everything works great, but when I try to run my tests using a CI build in VSTS, it doesn't recognize any tests in my test dll, stating:

> "Warning: No test is available in
>   c:\vsts_work\4\s\test\UnitTests\bin\Release\net452\UnitTests.dll".

I believe I have all of the important project.json bits in place:

```
  "testRunner": "mstest",

  "dependencies": {
    "dotnet-test-mstest": "1.0.1-preview",
    "MSTest.TestFramework": "1.0.1-preview"
  }
```

Of note, I am using an on-premise build agent, but I've proven I can log into that build agent using the service account under which the agent runs, and I can open visual studio and run the tests that way.

Also, while one could contrive it by looking at the above path, it is worth explicitly noting that I'm using the full framework.

Hoping someone out there has already conquered this one.

Comment: How did you configure the build task to run the test?

Comment: Yeah, I guess I left some details out didn't I.  I hinted at it, but to be clear, I created this project using the VS tooling, so I have a .sln file, and several xproj files.  On my local machine, I use Test Explorer for execution of my unit tests.  In my CI build, I'm using the "Visual Studio Test" test runner (again, sticking with the visual studio theme).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to use the "Visual Studio Test" action, thanks to this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37983495/mstest-no-xml-output-on-net-core-rc2)

The only thing that answer lacks is how to make it work in VSTS (the answer provides the command line).  To get it to work in VSTS, I put the following string in the "Test Assembly" parameter

```
**\test\**\project.json
```

And then put the rest of the command line arguments under "Advanced Execution Options" in the "Other console options" box.

```
/UseVsixExtensions:true /logger:trx
```

Hope this helps the next guy who is trying to stick with the visual studio tooling.

Answer (score 0):

To run a .NET Core test during the build, you can add a "Command Line" task to run "dotnet test" command and set the "Working Folder" to the path where the "project.json" file placed:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Two comments, first, I was intentionally going down the path of using visual studio tooling for everything rather than the dotnet CLI.  However (2nd comment), I'll take the bait.  I did switch over to using dotnet test, and while the log shows all my tests passing, I get no test results or code coverage reported back in VSTS.  I'll poke around and see what I can find, but if you or someone knows the answer off the cuff, that would be great.

Comment: @wikiwakit you can add the option -l trx to output test results and then add a 'Publish Test Results' task to your build defnition. Haven't figured out how to get code coverage results yet but it'll give you test results.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, getting the "Warning: No test is available" issue when I was looking right at the tests in Visual Studio.
It turns out the tests were trying to run in x86 when the application is 64 bit.

I recommend going to the Test menu at the top of Visual Studio, and open

Test>Test Settings>Default Processor Architecture>

and make sure the tests are on the right architecture, if you have a similar problem and the other answers aren't helping.