# VSTS Configuration to run xUnit tests for x64 platform

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, azure-pipelines, xunit.net

I need to make configuration for run xUnit test that build only for x64 platform. How can I do that?

I found [this](https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-test-results-in-vsts.html) article but it doesn't help.
I've got

> No test runs are available for this build.

Here are my properties in VSTS:

```
Test assemblies: **\*test*.dll  !**\obj\**
Search folder: src/Modules
Test platform version: Visual Studio 2017
Build platform: x64
Build configuration: Release
```

Comment: What's the type of your project, dotnet or dotnet core or something?

Comment: If you are using .net core project, you can also refer the setting for vs test task as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38860732/vsts-build-of-net-core-1-0-vstest-warning-no-test-is-available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to these steps:

1. Change BuildPlatform variable to x64
2. NuGet restore
3. Build solution (Platform: `$(BuildPlatform);` Configuration: `$(BuildConfiguration);` Visual Studio Version: `Visual Studio 2017`)
4. .Net Core (Preview) (Command: `test`; Projects: `**/*Test*.csproj`; Arguments: `--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --logger "trx;LogFileName=TEST-results.xml" /property:Platform=$(BuildPlatform))`
5. Publish Test Results (Test Result Format: `VSTest`; Test Results Files: `**/TEST-*.xml`)